# Imagemagick: can not make a static thumbnail from gif animation

Tags: php, imagemagick, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I use [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) scripts. The package contains a php script as well to process the files and to make thumbnails. Everything works fine but I need to create static thumbnails in case if users upload animated gif files.

Below is the function that creates thumbnails.

I have commented out everything for "Handle animated GIFs:" as I don't want animated thumbnails from animated gifs.

and added a line:

```
mail('my@email', 'file_path', "$file_path");
```

When uploading, I get emails with file path like: `/var/www/images/image.gif`

Then I added the following line to make thumbnails from the first frame

```
$file_path = $file_path[0];
mail('my@email', 'file_path', "$file_path");
```

Now I get empty email and thumbnails are not created. So, the variable $file_path[0] does not exist. Why?

How can I create static thumbnails from animated gifs?

```
protected function imagemagick_create_scaled_image($file_name, $version, $options) {

list($file_path, $new_file_path) =
$this->get_scaled_image_file_paths($file_name, $version);

$file_path = $file_path[0];

mail('my@email', 'file_path', "$file_path");

$resize = @$options['max_width']
.(empty($options['max_height']) ? '' : 'x'.$options['max_height']);
if (!$resize && empty($options['auto_orient'])) {
if ($file_path !== $new_file_path) {
return copy($file_path, $new_file_path);
}
return true;
}
$cmd = $this->options['convert_bin'];
if (!empty($this->options['convert_params'])) {
$cmd .= ' '.$this->options['convert_params'];
}
$cmd .= ' '.escapeshellarg($file_path);
if (!empty($options['auto_orient'])) {
$cmd .= ' -auto-orient';
}


//if ($resize) {
// Handle animated GIFs:
//$cmd .= ' -coalesce';
//if (empty($options['crop'])) {
//$cmd .= ' -resize '.escapeshellarg($resize.'>');
//} else {
//$cmd .= ' -resize '.escapeshellarg($resize.'^');
//$cmd .= ' -gravity center';
//$cmd .= ' -crop '.escapeshellarg($resize.'+0+0');
//}
// Make sure the page dimensions are correct (fixes offsets of animated GIFs):
//$cmd .= ' +repage';
//}


if (!empty($options['convert_params'])) {
$cmd .= ' '.$options['convert_params'];
}
$cmd .= ' '.escapeshellarg($new_file_path);

exec($cmd, $output, $error);
if ($error) {
error_log(implode('\n', $output));
return false;
}
return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, the variable $file_path[0] does not exist. Why?

I would assume that `$file_path` is a string, so `$file_path[0]` would access the character element in the string.

```php
php > $file_path = '/var/www/images/image.gif';
php > print $file_path;    //=> '/var/www/images/image.gif'
php > print $file_path[0]; //=> '/'
```

> How can I create static thumbnails from animated gifs?

The `[0]` should be appended to the file path *string value*, not within the PHP language.

```php
 $file_path .= '[0]';
 //=> '/var/www/images/image.gif[0]'
```